# How to scale and rotate textures in opengl es?

Tags: opengl-es

I am using opengl ES for my iphone game. To scale and rotate my object i do this:
   glScalef( scaleX , scaleY ,1);
   glRotatef(rotationZ, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)

I am using an ortho screen with orthof(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1). My problem is when i rotate objects, the image gets skewed. I understand why that is happening as i am scaling wrt to the screen size so while rotating it changes the image size. 
What can i do to prevent it from getting skewed.

```
glViewport(0,0, (GLint)screenWidth, (GLint)screenHeight);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrthof(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glPushMatrix();

glTranslatef(positionX, positionY,0.0f);

glScalef(scaleX , scaleY ,1);

glRotatef(rotationZ, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ortho projection that matches your aspect ratio of the screen rather than just sending a bunch of ones. Unless you have a square screen, your left/right shouldn't be the same as your top/bottom or you will see skew.

Comment: I tried giving the left and right of the orthogonal projection as -aspectR, and aspectR but I still see skewness. The only way i figured out to prevent skewness was to treat a rectangular image as a square and then scale it as squares.

Comment: If you draw a square and don't see a square or if you draw a rectangle and don't see a rectangle, then you are making your life more difficult by not first setting up a proper projection matrix. You don't want to have to use a modelview matrix to compensate for a poorly configured projection matrix.

Comment: also, make sure you are setting your viewport correctly, as that can also cause objects to not appear in correct shape

Comment: I have added the way i set up the viewport and the projection matrix

Comment: Unless your screen is a perfect square, passing all 1s to your ortho is going to give you skew. You should pass to your ortho the same aspect ratio of your screen.

Comment: also, your code is not OpenGL ES 2.0 so you should remove that tag. You are using 1.1.